# Why would my Windows shortcut stop working for accessing the address bar on taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm not sure why, but the shortcut I've used to access the address-bar, shown below, has stopped workin.

[image]

I'v used `Win-B , Shift-Tab` before , but now it has quit working.

The `Windows+B` *does* highlight an icon in the notifications area, but when I hit `Shift-Tab` then that part doesn't work correctly. I have a suspicion that it relates to cool to me also running an RDP program in the background?

It may be an example of one of those strange bugs that pops up Now & again.

thnx

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what's wrong?  When you input an address, does your default browser appear?  Is there an error message?

Comment: @Colyn1337 - thank you, I've added some more